# Tokyo Cabinet and SQLite compatible interfaces?

Tags: api, sqlite, tokyo-cabinet

I was wondering if anyone has seen a library that abstracts away SQLite and Tokyo-Cabinet to the same API. Basically I'm looking for something that will allow me to test and dev with SQLite, and later move to TC for production.

Anyways the language I'm using specifically is Lua, but I'm sure such a library doesn't exist for Lua, so a Library that does this in **any other language is also ok** since I can develop something similar for Lua based on that.

Answer (score 4):

DataMapper, the default ORM for Merb (written in Ruby), might help.  Take a look at an experimental [DataMapper adapter for Tokyo-Cabinet](http://github.com/makoto/dm-tokyo-cabinet-adapter/tree/master).  DataMapper's already got SQLite3 support so you may be able to compare the two.

Comment: thanks for the link, gotta check out the implementation for hints now

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but since [Carbonado](http://carbonado.sourceforge.net/) supports RDBMSs (Oracle) and "persisted b-trees" (BDB), it could definitely support both.